# InternetExplorer Webdriver with nativeEvents

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a menu hidden in a button, when the button is clicked, then the menu is shown, the structure of hidden menu is follow:

```
<button id="buttonID"></button> 
<ul class="ulClass">
   <li>
   <li>
   <li>
   <li>
</ul>
```

I want to click on second item, so I did:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ulClass']/li[2]")).click();
```

It works fine with FF and Chrome, but doesn't work with IE, the reason because I gave the nativeEvents to false to IE:

```
capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
```

This capabilities is set for the whole test with IE, without it, the whole test won't work, and now I just need to click on this item but can't because of this capabilities.

Is there any workaround to click on this item but I still skip this capability, because apparently we can't toggle capabilities in run time. Thanks.

Comment: I am not trying to answer your question, but out of curiosity wanted to know what all capabilities you are setting for IE?

Comment: @mk08: I use 2 capabilities: capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
         capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all suggestions, I solved this with JavascriptExecutor:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try JavaScript instead native clicks

var element=webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ulClass']/li[2]"));
Driver.ExecuteJavaScript("arguments[0].click();",element);

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried this before I posted my question, but it didn't work for any broswer

Comment: Can you an insight what went wrong? Any exceptions?

Comment: Error is "Element is not displayed" or "Element is not visible", but I took a screenshot with webdriver, and the element is visible in the viewport